# What is the difference between these backward training methods in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am a 3-month DL freshman who is doing small NLP projects with Pytorch.
Recently I am trying to reappear a GAN network introduced by a paper, using my own text data, to generate some specific kinds of question sentences.

> Here is some background... If you have no time or interest about it, just kindly read the following question is OK.
> As that paper says, the generator is firstly trained normally with normal question data to make that the output at least looks like a real question. Then by using an auxiliary classifier's result (of classifying the outputs), the generator is trained again to just generate the specific (several unique categories) questions.
> However, as the paper do not reveal its code, I have to do the code all myself. I have these three training thoughts, but I do not know their differences, could you kindly tell me about it? 
> If they have almost the same effect, could you tell me which is more recommended in Pytorch's grammar? Thank you very much!

Suppose the discriminator loss to generator is loss_G_D, the classifier loss to generator is loss_G_C, and loss_G_D and loss_G_C has the same shape, i.e. [batch_size, loss value], then what is the difference?
1.

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_D = loss_func1(discriminator(generated_data))
loss_G_C = loss_func2(classifier(generated_data))
loss = loss_G+loss_C
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

2. 

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_D = loss_func1(discriminator(generated_data))
loss_G_D.backward()
loss_G_C = loss_func2(classifier(generated_data))
loss_G_C.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

3. 

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_D = loss_func1(discriminator(generated_data))
loss_G_D.backward()
optimizer.step()

optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_G_C = loss_func2(classifier(generated_data))
loss_G_C.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Additional info: I observed that the classifier's classification loss is always very big compared with generator's loss, like -300 vs 3. So maybe the third one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

`loss.backward()` backpropagates the error and assigns a gradient for every parameter along the way that has `requires_grad=True`.

`optimizer.step()` updates the model parameters using their stored gradients

`optimizer.zero_grad()` sets the gradients to 0, so that you can backpropagate your loss and update your model parameters for each batch without interfering with other batches.

`1` and `2` are quite similar, but if your model uses batch statistics or you have an adaptive optimizer they will probably perform differently. However, for instance, if your model doesn't use batch statistics and you have a plain old SGD optimizer, they will produce the same result, even though `1` would be faster since you do the backprop only once.

`3` is a completely different case, since you update your model parameters with `loss_G_D.backward()` and `optimizer.step()` before processing and backpropagating `loss_G_C`.

Given all of these, it's up to you which one to choose depending on your application.

Comment: 1 and 2 should be identical, since gradients are accumulating independent of each other and there is no update step inbetween?

Comment: @unlut Yes. Since differentiation is a linear operator, backpropagating the sum of losses is equivalent to backpropagating them individually and accumulating the gradients

Comment: But you are saying they are not always same.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am using the Adam optimizer so I think maybe between 1 and 2, 2 is better? And as I think... As they optimize the network from different aspects, maybe... between 2 and 3, 3 is more reasonable.

Comment: @unlut I'm saying they will probably be not the same in case the optimizer is adaptive or you have a batchnorm layer or something. But e.g. if you use SGD without batchnorm or other types of batch-dependent layers it should be the same

Comment: @PeterNova I think 1 is better since it makes more sense to me to add losses and backpropagate just once, and it is faster

Comment: @abe They should be same regardless, adaptive optimizers use values of "previous" gradients, not current ones and calling backward alone will not update previous gradients.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Well, but for my application...(in the background part) As these two loss will optimize the network from different aspects, one makes the generated question sentence like a sentence, the other ensures the generated sentence has a specific style... (While their scale is -300 vs 3). So I wonder maybe 3 is more reasonable for what I want to realize? Wouldn't 1 make the generated sentence look wired due to the effect of big classification loss? (Ok I should test it myself XD..)

Comment: @PeterNova you can assign weights to the losses you are adding if you're worried about that

Comment: Wait, I just think of that... Like I use method 1, and make loss=loss_G_D+0.01loss_G_C. (scale is 3 vs -300 mentioned before) But won't this cause gradient too small and even vanishing? Or should I give more weights for classifier loss..?(sorry for asking rookie questions always...

Comment: @PeterNova no need to be sorry, I also consider myself a rookie :) I cannot say anything for sure, you need to experiment with different options yourself. But, as a rule of thumb, if you want to take weighted averages of your losses, your weights should add up to 1, so that you won't have to adjust your learning rate for each experiment.